# How do I dynamically set a static "#define" variable in a header (.h) file?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sharekit

I am using an open source component in my iOS project (sharekit), and they defined static variables in the header file.  For example, in `SHKConfig.h` they define the **App Name** as:

```
#define SHKMyAppName            @"My App Name"
```

What I would like to do is make this dynamic; I don't want to hard-code those variables in that specific file.  Since there is obviously no `viewDidLoad` method in a header file (as far as I know), how could I possibly dynamically assign this variable?

Is this even possible?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: How are you compiling your source code? You could probably add a `-D SHKMyAppName="Whatever You Want"` to the compiler options. Honestly not sure if this works in LVVM, but does in GCC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#define` is always evaluated during code compilation. You should modify the library to get this functionality.

Another solution is the following. Create some class `Provider` with a

```
+ (NSString *)getYourConstant;
```

method and use the following macro

```
#import "Provider.h"

#define kTheConstantYouNeed [Provider getYourConstant]
```

Comment: will this be evaluated at runtime? Or will that method only be called during compilation? (your code example)

Comment: During code compilation all the occurrences of SHKMyAppName will be replaced (as a string) with the right hand side. So during runtime instead of having @"My App Name", you will get an actual method call.

Comment: perfect! thank you!! one last question, in the files where that method is being injected, do I have to import the utilities class (Provider.h in your example) or because it is imported in the macro header file I don't have to?

Comment: Nope, you should not. If a file has access to this constant, it will also have all the imports from the file where it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ifdef` macro preprocessor to redefine the variable at compile time. There is no way you could "change that variable" since it's not even a variable to begin with. It's a MACRO that replaces all occurrences of `SHKMyAppName` with `@"My App Name`.

Here's is what you could do. Define a compiler variable (you can do that in XCode project configurations) with the project name you are building. Then, replace `#define` with:

```
#if defined(PROJECT_APP_01_BUILD)
#define SHKMyAppName @"My App 01"
#elif defined(PROJECT_APP_02_BUILD)
#define SHKMyAppName @"My App 02"
#elif defined(PROJECT_APP_03_BUILD)
#define SHKMyAppName @"My App 03"
#endif
```

That way, when you are compiling **App 01**, macro `SHKMyAppName` will be replaced by `@"My App 01"'. When you are compiling **App 02**, macro`SHKMyAppName`will be replaced by`@"My App 02"'. And so on, so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You could move these defines to a single appinfo.h file and include it within other headers.

This might also be a good place for version info.

E.g.

In SHKConfig.h:

```
#include "MyAppInfo.h"
#define SHKMyAppName    MyAppName // define MyAppName elsewhere
```

And in MapAppInfo.h:

```
#define MyAppName "Bla bla"
```

Or...

In SHKConfig.h:

```
#define SHKMyAppName    MyAppName // define MyAppName elsewhere
```

And in app's compiler settings add:

```
-DMyAppName=\"Bla bla\"
```

Comment: This is true, but has nothing to do with the original problem: to get some kind of runtime evaluation of a #define statement in a third party library.

Comment: Read again - the word "runtime" was not mentioned once in the question. The problem stated was "I don't want to hard-code those variables in **that** specific file." Besides, as you know, #define is processed at compile-time, not run-time.

Comment: The fact that some words are not present in the question do not change its sense for me. I really think that stackoverflow should be a place where people tend to help each other and not just automatically answer questions without even trying to get into the problem.

Comment: @Anton, I agree with @Danny.  I never mentioned run-time in my question and he did answer my original question correctly, even though you provided a solution that worked better for me; so I don't know if it was worth a down vote.  I'm going to give @Anton the accepted solution because it provided an answer that I originally didn't think of, but turned out to be better suited for my problem.  If this is not consistent with SO guidelines please let me know and I will rectify. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Sorry, I really did think Angelo was meaning what I understood.